# Preciso comparar duas colunas de um dataframe para criar uma lista de resultados ainda não obtidos

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Eu tenho um dataframe com duas colunas, a primeiro contendo um número identificação e a segunda com os resultados para esse número. Eu preciso compará-las e criar uma lista com os números de identificação que ainda não possuem valores associados.

```
  df.head()

  N   V
  1  NaN
  2  0.367608
  3  NaN
  4  0.312892
  5  NaN
```

Eu consigo separar as colunas em listas, mas não consigo comparar as listas uma posição por vez.

```
for col in df[['V']]:
    print (col)
    for v in df[col]:
        resultados.append(v)

for col in df[['N']]:
    print (col)
    for v in df[col]:
        amostras.append(v)
```

Comment: Talvez crie uma coluna com um bool, df['V'].equals(df['N'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode verificar os valores ausentes na coluna V com a função **isna** e retornar a coluna N, transformando em uma lista com o **to_list**

```
df['N'].loc[df['V'].isna()].to_list()
```

Saída:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Obrigado. Eu tinha conseguido resolver convertendo para um dicionário, mas essa solução é muito mais simples.